# how to force ajax to use browser cache to not load the updated json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

might look like weired question. I have ajax call to json file, in request and response header nothing says don't use cache and in browser control Disable cache is not ticked. what should I do more to force ajax not to load the updated json from my local???

---

update: what I want is, I want to update the json in my local without getting updated on browser ajax call.

---

I am changing the last modified file attribute using following command:
touch -d "4 days ago" 0.json

---

thanks in advance ..
[image]

Comment: check for modified flag.

Comment: please check the command I'm using to change last modified file attribute in question update

Comment: so you want to change the actual file, but "trick" the browser into thinking it hasn't changed?

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

AJAX request cache follows the same rules as normal HTTP request cache. It can vary from browser to browser.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce CDN caching issue while loading json using same browser  in my local development environment, that's why I need to reproduce the issue to be able to test my solution :)